# What is equivalent function of a Microsoft Word Quick part in Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to display "last save date" automatically in a cell in excel. Writing VBA code may not feasible as the people creating the excel sheets may not be familiar with writing VBA codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, they wont have to write this code, if you pack it as an add-in - but you/they will have to use macros - no other way to do this.

```
Public Function LastSaveTime() As Variant
    Dim fs, f
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
    'you can delete the debug.print, it's just for debug ;)
    Debug.Print "Modified: " & f.DateLastModified
    LastSaveTime = f.DateLastModified
End Function
```

Adapted from excel-help, looking for DateLastModified.

Save this in a Module, then follow a "distibute as add-in"-howto.

Now, if I didn't make any basic error, this should provide any workbook with a new worksheet-function `=LastSaveTime()`, which returns the DateLastModified of the active workbook. There might be a catch, because of the activeworkbook - it might be saver to use an `application.caller` construct, when using this as an add-in.